# How to pass variable from uitableview to second tableview using didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5

i want to pass the variable from a view controller to another one, so that when the user selects a certain row in the first table view, the application will take him to another view controller in which the details of the selected item will appear.
This is my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSString *selectedAuthors = [theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    Details *dvController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"]; //Or whatever identifier you have defined in your storyboard





    dvController.selectedAuthors = selectedAuthors;

    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:authorNAme delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

   // Display Alert Message
    authorNAme =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:[theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] intValue];
 [messageAlert show];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```

selectedAuthors is a string
authorName is a global variable in which i want to store the content of the selected row.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: by `dv.selectedAuthors = selectedAuthors;` you are already passing "data" to the second view controller. You should display the details based on selectedAuthors in the details view controller.

Comment: Please check the link it will show u the specific problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897149/how-to-send-the-details-of-a-selected-cell-to-another-view-controller

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using storyboards.

In this case, to send information to the next view controller you have to implement

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

This method gets called every time a segue is about to be performed.
For instance, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can save the row's information in a dictionnary and pass it to the next view controller in the prepareForSegue method.

For detailed information you can check out Apple's sample project named SimpleDrillDown. It does the same thing you need to do:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Being new to Xcode, i have already tried this suggestion, but it didn't work..can u provide me with a snippet plz. Many thanks

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897149/how-to-send-the-details-of-a-selected-cell-to-another-view-controller

Comment: Have you tried to look into the project I recommended you? If you have and it didn't work, please update your question so I can see what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSString *titleString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Element number :  %d",indexPath.row] autorelease];
```

This is the simplest function used to send variables and it just came out of nowhere! For anyone lost this is the best function!!