# Keep search bar fixed position while scrolling tableView

Tags: xcode, uisearchbar

How can i keep the uiSearch bar i created in Xcode 4.3.3 fixed on top while scrolling the table view?
Any thoughts?

Comment: can u plz explain ur question a bit more. not sure what u have done so cant give a sure shot answer

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**
If u have used the Interface builder to add the search bar, make sure that it is not added as the subview of the tableview (this makes the search bar as a part of the table, which scrolls along with the table). Checkout the link below, and avoid it. This link shows how a search bar becomes a subview of the table. This is not what u want. Just drag the search bar outside of the Table view in ur interface builder, so that it becomes a part of the view.

I have added second image to show how u can find the solution to ur problem.

If u want to add the search bar programatically, then just add it as-

```
[self.view addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

Set the frame of this search bar accordingly.

[image: This should not be done to if u want the search bar not to scroll]

[image]

Comment: I tried to initiate the search bar as shown in the pic, but still when the application loads and i try to scroll down/up , the search bar will scroll along with the tableview.

Comment: I think i couldn't make myself clear. The pic is just for illustration. The thing in the pic is the opposite of what u want. This pic example is what u need to avoid. in ur IB, just drag the search bar outside of the Table view, so that it is a part of the view just like the table view...

Answer (score 0):

how did you create them in the nib file? do not put the search bar on the UITableView. they should be separated.You can put the search bar at the top of the tableview but not on it.